# Android composite background

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do a composite background. There are 3 images, let's call them "И","О","N" and I want make the "O" part as resizable color and "И", "N" will be an images. 
How can I achive this using drawable xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). There you can specify stretchable background areas.